# How to select tuples that begin with a certain substring in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks as follows

```
> df[1:10,c("Uri","Latency")]
                                                                                                       Uri
1                          /filters/test_group_1/test_datasource%20with%20space/test_application_alias_100
2                                                          /applications?includeDashboards&includeMappings
3                                                                   /applications/test_application_alias_1
4                                                          /applications?includeDashboards&includeMappings
5                                                                 /applications/test_application_alias_200
6                                                                 /applications/test_application_alias_100
7    /filters/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001/test_datasource%20with%20space/test_application_alias_0
8                                             /dashboards?dashboard=test_dashboard_alias_9&includeMappings
9               /filters/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001/test_dataSource_1/test_application_alias_100
10 /filters/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001/test_datasource%20with%20space/test_application_alias_100
   Latency
1      296
2     1388
3       58
4      833
5      239
6       60
7      217
8       36
9       86
10     112
```

I want to select only those rows that start with /applications. Note that the rest of the Uri could be anything, and is not important.

I could've got the exact matches by doing the following,

```
df[which(df$Uri == "/applications"),c("Uri","Latency")]
```

However, since, I am looking for a substring, I understand, I may have to do some wildcard processing, which in SQL would look like.

```
select * from <table_name> where Uri like '%/applications%'
```

How can I do the same in R

Comment: Maybe just `df[substr(df$Uri, 1, nchar("/applications"))=="/applications",]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `df$Uri` is a character vector, I'd go with with:

```
df[startsWith(df$Uri, "/applications"), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a regular expression:

```
df[ grepl( "^\\/applications" , df[, "Uri"] ) , c("Uri","Latency") ]
```